# Update Batch File: Implementing Conditional Arguments

Tags: windows, batch-file

I work in IT help-desk, new to coding but put together this batch file to get our nightly updates completed faster:

```
@echo off
echo.
echo          RTC Customer Care - Variety Pre-Eigen Updater
echo      (Continue along with 'ENTER' to reach desired update.)
echo.
pause
echo.
echo ====================================
echo Transfer Required Files to C: Drive?
echo ====================================
echo.
echo.
pause
cd /d h:\smsback
call vwiw3net2.bat
echo.
echo                     (Finished copying files)
echo             Note: If transfer failed, re-run updater.
pause
echo.
echo ===========================
echo Execute Part 1/2 of Update?
echo ===========================
echo.
echo.
pause
echo                 (Follow prompts till completion)
start /d "c:\smsback\1_win3_1" WindowsInstaller-KB893803-v2-x86.exe
pause
echo.
echo ===========================
echo Execute Part 2/2 of Update?
echo ===========================
echo.
echo.
pause
echo                 (Follow prompts till completion)
echo          Note: 2nd update takes a few minutes to display.
start /d "c:\smsback\2_net2" NetFx20SP2_x86.exe
pause
echo.
echo.
echo ==================================================
echo ATTENTION: Register will RESTART to finish update.
echo ==================================================
echo.
pause
shutdown.exe /r /t 05
(goto) 2>nul & del "%~f0"
```

What would be some good conditional arguments for verifying that an update installed? File size? Just don't want to have to run the script to get to update 2 and open/close out of previous steps.

Comment: Unescaped parentheses, those give me goosebumps, even though they dont seem to misbehave in this script . . .

Comment: Yeah mistype when I copied it over :0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First, opening a command prompt window and running there `start /?` or `help start` results in getting help displayed for this command. It can be read on output help about `/Dpath` and other options of this command. There is no space between `/D` and path.

Second, **start** interprets first double quoted string as title. Therefore `""` or `"useful title"` should be specified on command line with **start** as first parameter if any other parameter is enclosed in double quotes.

Third, if **start** is used to install from within a batch file, it is better to use this command with parameter `/wait` as it is not possible to run multiple installations parallel. `msiexec` used to install each security update does not allow running more than one install/repair/uninstall operation at the same time.

Fourth, most executables of Windows security updates are console applications and can be run from within a batch file without the need to use command **start** at all. So instead of

```
start /d "c:\smsback\1_win3_1" WindowsInstaller-KB893803-v2-x86.exe
```

it would be better to use just:

```
C:\smsback\1_win3_1\WindowsInstaller-KB893803-v2-x86.exe
```

Fifth, the executables of Windows security updates all exit with a value greater 0 on an error and with 0 on success. Therefore after running a security update executable without command **start** as written above a line like the following could be used to check return value of the executable.

```
if errorlevel 1 echo Failed to install KB893803-v2-x86, error code %ERRORLEVEL%.
```

See [Windows Installer Error Messages](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa372835.aspx) and [MsiExec.exe and InstMsi.exe Error Messages](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa368542.aspx).

And finally which updates are installed already can be queried from Windows registry key `HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\Software\Microsoft\Updates` and its subkeys.

Comment: Thank you so much, your advice was precise and helpful. Working on a revision as we speak.